# Regex Find string if it comes after another string

Tags: regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

Can anyone please help me find a regex for the following. I am trying to match the number after "Processed" but ONLY if the previous line contains the string "Backed".

I have been using "(?<=Processed )(.*?)(?= bytes)" to get the number, but I would like to use preg-match-all and ONLY match the Backed up numbers, not the verified numbers....

Here is an example string:

```
Backed up 77914 files in 16615 directories.  
Processed 19,500,663,915 bytes in  10 minutes and  27 seconds.  
Throughput rate: 1780 MB/min*  

Contents verified.  
Processed 13,694,118,197 bytes in  1 minute and  41 seconds.  
Throughput rate: 7758 MB/min*
```

Comment: Regex operates on a per-line bases, so you need two regex one to see if prev line contains _Backed_ and another to get the number after _Processed_ (if the prev passes)

Answer (score 0):

this is the closest I can get based on your requirements:

```
(?<=Backed)[^\n]+[\n\r]+.*Processed\s(?<num>(\d+\,*)+)\sbytes
```

The result is in group `num`

I have tested it with the following input:

> Backed up 77914 files in 16615 directories. Processed 19,500,663,915 bytes in 10 minutes and 27 seconds. Throughput rate: 1780 MB/min
>
> Contents verified. Processed 13,694,118,197 bytes in 1 minute and 41 seconds. Throughput rate: 7758 MB/min
>
> up 77914 files in 16615 directories. Processed 19,500,663,915 bytes in 10 minutes and 27 seconds. Throughput rate: 1780 MB/min
>
> Contents verified. Processed 13,694,118,197 bytes in 1 minute and 41 seconds. Throughput rate: 7758 MB/min

..and it matches only the first occurrence of 13,694,118,197

Comment: Yes this is working for me, I can then get the data I need with this. Is there any change you could please show me the regex for the same scenario but it needs to first match the words "Backup of" and "Processed" could be any number of lines below, but the next instance of.... eg..  

    **Backup of** "Search Service Application\Index files 2  (SHAREPOINT2\264e318d-a7ab-4e68-858f-2b35786beba5)"  
Backup set #2313 on storage media #263  
Backup set description: "SQL Databases Full"  
Backup Method: Full - Back up entire database  
**Processed 413360** bytes in  3 seconds.

Comment: Errm sorry i have never used this site before... Above in my search string each time it says "Backup" that is a new line, then Processed is also on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
(?<=.*Backed.*)[\d,]+(?= bytes)
```

given the input

```
Backed up 77914 files in 16615 directories. Processed 19,500,663,915 bytes in 10 minutes and 27 seconds. Throughput rate: 1780 MB/min
Contents verified. Processed 13,694,118,197 bytes in 1 minute and 41 seconds. Throughput rate: 7758 MB/min
Backed up 77914 files in 16615 directories. Processed 19,500,663,915 bytes in 10 minutes and 27 seconds. Throughput rate: 1780 MB/min
Contents verified. Processed 13,694,118,197 bytes in 1 minute and 41 seconds. Throughput rate: 7758 MB/min
```

It will match

```
19,500,663,915
19,500,663,915
```

It can be that PCRE library does not support infinite repetition inside lookbehind. If thats the case we can look for an alternative

Comment: I think that he wants to match 13,694,118,197 if the line before contains 'Backed'

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned im using PHP preg_match and if i use buckleys awnser i get:Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 14